# Joining multiple jsons to one json object with duplicate keys

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to join multiple json objects into one Json. But I am having issues merging on json objects that have the same key.

If I have jsons that look like this:

```
{K1 - V1}
{K2 - V2}
{K3 - V3}
{K1 - V4}
```

I want to output:

```
{K1 - [V1, V4], K2- V2, K3 - V3}
```

I can merge the Jsons that have unique keys with this code:

```
    private JSONObject mergeJsons(ArrayList<JSONObject> arr) {
        JSONObject mergedObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            for (JSONObject o : arr) {
                Iterator i = o.keys();
                String tmp_key;
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    tmp_key = (String) i.next();
                    mergedObj.put(tmp_key, o.get(tmp_key));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("Json Exception");
            return null;
        }
        return mergedObj;
    }
```

But I am trying to get the multivalued elements (i.e. V1 and V4) to become a Json Array. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Where you do `mergedObj.put` you instead have to have logic that does the following (in pseudocode)

```
v = mergedObj.get(key)
if (v == null)
    mergedObj.put(key,value)
else
    if (v is not a list)
        temp = v
        v = new list()
        v.add(temp)
    v.add(value)
```

This leaves you with a map where some values are single objects and some values are lists (arrays).  You should probably regularize it so all values are arrays.